# error 00289 while projecting raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system

I tried to project satellite image of pixel size 2.5m*2.5m. It's in wgs84 UTM zone 44 North. I tried to project it to nepal_87 but failed. The error massage displayed was 'error-000289,failed to alter spatial reference.'

Also this satellite image and shape files of the area are not displayed at same time, only which the one loaded first is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Error 000289 is probably an ArcGIS error message. The complete description says:

> The spatial reference of the dataset cannot be altered. The dataset
>   may be in use by another application and therefore locked.

The error message makes it sound like you tried to use Define Projection or the data's property page to change the coordinate system. That updates the metadata information only. You must use the Project Raster tool to create a raster in a different coordinate system. The error message implies that the raster was in use (was it displayed in ArcMap? Or did you have its folder selected in ArcCatalog?) by another process.

Also, do the raster and shapefiles not line up while the raster has its original coordinate system of WGS84 UTM zone 44 North? If so, that implies that either the raster or the shapefiles have the wrong coordinate system. Please feel free to edit your question with the extents of the raster and the shapefiles, plus the coordinate system of the shapefiles.